# how to read data from firestore flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i want to read data from firestore in a listtile i dont want to use streambuilder i want to access the documents field individually i try this but not working

```
class ProductList extends StatelessWidget {


  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot =  Firestore.instance.collection("listofprods").document('ac1').snapshots();


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)
                ),
                child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot['name']),//here error
                ),
              )
            ],
```

Comment: Try as: Text(snapshot.data['name']),

Comment: error: the getter 'data' isn;t define for the class Stream<DocumentSnapshot>

Comment: Update your query:-  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot = Firestore.instance.collection("listofprods").document('ac1').snapshots().get();

Answer (score 10):

```
As Per 2021 :
 streamSnapshot.data.docs
```

> Documents Changes to doc .

```
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('chats/XYSDa16jZBO5CUMwIk0h/messages')
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: streamSnapshot.data.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) =>
                  Text(streamSnapshot.data.docs[index]['text']),
            );
          },
        ));

  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';


class WeightChart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WeightChartState createState() => _WeightChartState();
}

class _WeightChartState extends State<WeightChart>  {
  dynamic data;

  Future<dynamic> getData() async {

    final DocumentReference document =   Firestore.instance.collection("listofprods").document('ac1');

    await document.get().then<dynamic>(( DocumentSnapshot snapshot) async{
     setState(() {
       data =snapshot.data;
     });
    });
 }

 @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Weight'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(data['name']),//here error
              ),
            )
          ]
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: will you please tell me what is the .then function how it works  i dont know anything about it i m asking it to improve my skills thanks

Comment: @LalitRawat ```.then()``` is called after the function call is success. For every ```Future``` function, there will be a ```then()``` callback. In the current context, once the data is loaded from Firestore.

Answer (score 3):

without stream and in a stateless widget, I made it with:

- Function running at first in build
- This function need to be "async-await" in order to get data
- Use of toString, get and data for access the desire element.

code:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

DocumentSnapshot snapshot; //Define snapshot

class ProductList extends StatelessWidget {
  void getData()async{ //use a Async-await function to get the data
    final data =  await Firestore.instance.collection("listofprods").document('ac1').get(); //get the data
     snapshot = data;
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getData(); //run the function in build
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)
                ),
                child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.data['name'].toString()),//ok no errors.
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the last code maybe gets some errors on diferents versions of cloud_firestore the version i use is

- cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
- firebase_core: ^0.4.5

and other error is a red screen with some null on text, this is fix with a FutureBuilder instead to call directly de data, in this way:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class ProductList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<String> data2() async {
      var data1 = (await Firestore.instance
              .collection('listofprods')
              .document('ac1')
              .get())
          .data['name']
          .toString();
      return data1;
    }
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: FutureBuilder(
                    future: data2(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      print(snapshot.data);
                      return Text(snapshot.data);
                    },
                  ), //ok no errors.
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `StreamBuilder`

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('books').snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError)
      return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Loading...');
      default:
        return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(document['title']),
              subtitle: new Text(document['author']),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
```

Comment: It works but it doesn't update the listView. I have to restart by pressing 'r' in terminal. What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

This works in FlutterFire! I used [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) and [await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await).

By using `DocumentSnapshot`, you can get the document including document fields and its values.

> A DocumentSnapshot contains data read from a document in your Cloud
> Firestore database. The data can be extracted with data() or
> get() to get a specific field.

The keyword `await` will wait until any async functions are finished.

> You can use the await keyword to get the completed result of an
> asynchronous expression. The await keyword only works within an async
> function.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

// Get document with ID totalVisitors in collection dashboard
await db.collection('dashboard').doc('totalVisitors').get()
  .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                            
    // Get value of field date from document dashboard/totalVisitors
    firestoreDate = documentSnapshot.data()['date'];

    // Get value of field weekOfYear from document dashboard/totalVisitors
    firestoreWeek = documentSnapshot.data()['weekOfYear'];

  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Streambuilder` for stream in `flutter`

```
StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
     stream: Firestore.instance.collection("listofprods").document('ac1').snapshots(),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();

       return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
     },
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class DataFetch extends StatefulWidget {
  const DataFetch({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _DataFetchState createState() => _DataFetchState();
}
class _DataFetchState extends State<DataFetch> {
  List<Model> list=[];
  void fetchData()async{
    var data=await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Items").get();
    for(int i=0;i<data.docs.length;i++){
      Model model=Model(data.docs[i].data()['title'], data.docs[i].data()['price'],data.docs[i].data()['imageURL'],data.docs[i].data()['desc'], data.docs[i].data()['seller']);
      list.add(model);
    }
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child: list.length==0? Center(child: Text("No Post")):ListView.builder(itemCount: list.length,
            itemBuilder:(_,index){
              return MyUI(list[index].title, list[index].url, list[index].price, list[index].desc, list[index].seller);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Widget MyUI(String title,String url,String price,String desc,String seller){
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(title),
          Image.network(url),
          Text(price),
          Text(desc),
          Text(seller)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Model{
  String title,price,url,desc,seller;
  Model(this.title,this.price,this.url,this.desc,this.seller);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!

Answer (score 0):

From the new Cloud Firestore it changed to

```
`FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;`
```

this from `Firestore.instance.collection("listofprods")`

So if you want to To create a new Firestore instance, call the instance getter on FirebaseFirestore like above mentioned code.

Reference: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/