# Flutter + Firebase: how can I iterate through subcollections?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an Instagram clone with Flutter and Cloud Firestore and I'm trying to structure the database like this:

Collection ("Timeline") > Document (each photo item) > Map with item photo, title, etc > Comments subcollection > Comment item > Map of comment and author name.

Which actually looks like this:

```
/TimeLine/itemID/comments/commentItemID/
```

To read the item title, for instance, is easy. I can render a Listview.builder and use:

```
snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(i)['itemTitle']
```

But how can I iterate through the Comments subcollection of each item? I tried a nested Listview and this, but I can't access the subcollection of elementAt(index):

```
snapshot.data.documents               
        .elementAt(i).collection('comments').elementAt(c)['commentAuthor']
```

Or is there a better way to structure this?

[Screenshot of Firestore setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paznB.jpg)

Comment: this is not an economic approach and you cant query collections you can only query documents

Comment: Please, include an image of your firestore object.

Comment: I've included one now. Thanks!

Comment: Please have a look into the following [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65034149/8791788) where it is an answer posted for your concerns. Also please bear in mind, you can't query collections, you will need to query the documents in a collection to get the data. Please also have a look into the following [tutorial](https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/04/04/using-cloud-firestore-in-flutter/#retrieve-subcollection).

Answer (score 2):

The following code is to Retrieve and Display Snapshot or to retrieve a subcollection:

In order to view the data, we have to retrieve all documents or particular document of that collection. For retrieving particular document we have to specify document id.

```
void getData() {
  databaseReference
      .collection("comments")
      .getDocuments()
      .then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    snapshot.documents.forEach((f) => print('${f.data}}'));
  });
}
```

Retrieve SubCollection

```
firestoreInstance.collection("comments").get().then((querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
    firestoreInstance
        .collection("comments")
        .doc(result.id)
        .collection("SUBCOLLECTION")
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
        print(result.data());
      });
    });
  });
});
}
```

Please also have a look into the following tutorials [1](https://petercoding.com/firebase/2020/04/04/using-cloud-firestore-in-flutter/#retrieve-a-document).

Comment: Best example for looping through sub collection I ever found! Awesome job!