# how to query the subcollections in firestore using flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need to query Firestore and the Firestore structure:

```
root-->payment-->(user IDs)--->(random doc ID)-->(data like paymentid: 1234, paid: 50)
(col)  (doc)       (col)           (doc)              (fields)
```

My query is like I need to get all values whose `paid>0` is my query.

What I have tried is?

```
var query = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
query.collection("root").where("paid",">",0);
```

But it didn't return any data and I know this is not the correct format. How can achieve this?

Can even I query this structure using Flutter? or Is there any better structure to implement?

Comment: Do you want to get all values whose paid>0 of a single users, or of all users?

Comment: @AlexMamo All the users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual query won't return the expected result since under the "root" collection there are no documents that contain a "paid" field. There would be however a solution in which you could use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) but only if your subcollection would have had the **same** name. Since the name of the subcollections are actual user IDs, this solution doesn't apply. So what you can only do is to create a reference that points to a single user:

```
root-->payment-->(user IDs)
```

And perform the following query:

```
var query = FirebaseFirestore.instance
     .collection("root").document("payment")
     .collection(userId).where("paid", ">" ,0);
```

But this query will only return the documents that correspond to a single user.

> Is there any better structure to implement?

Yes, there is. Please check a possible structure below:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- users (collection)
       |
       --- $uid (document)
            |
            --- payments (collection)
                 |
                 --- paymentid: 1234
                 |
                 --- paid: 50
```

In this way, you can perform a collection group query and get all documents where the "paid" field holds a value greater than `0`:

```
var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
var finalQuery = db.collectionGroup("payments").where("paid", ">", 0);
```

Comment: One more thing, what's the syntax to get all the document ID and it's data... Like printing it...

Comment: You might try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59529177/how-to-read-data-from-firestore-flutter). If you have a hard time implementing it, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried, so I and other Firebase developers can help you.