# How To Get Field Name And Field Value Separately From List<Object?> From Firestore flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get Field Name and Field Value separately from a Firestore snapshot which is now returned as List<Object?>.

For example, I want to store Field Name in a special variable i.e **fieldName** and Field Value in another variable such as **fieldValue**.

**Here is an example of output that I get from Firestore:**

```
[{1. Elements Of Trade Setups: https://mega.nz/file/J0pDzQJZ#yCqXjJ-ASDcHhFOp9whZjLiHIB69U3Mh5ubsaPiL8uA}]
```

**Here is the screenshot from firestore:**

[image: Firestore Screenshot]

**Here is my code so far for getting data from firestore:**

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: videoProvider,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                var data =
                    snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();

                print(data);
```

Comment: can you refer to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/q/59529177/15774176 is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to call variable of value with this:

```dart
developerProvider.developerSolos[0].kehadiran
```